# How can get Friends' userID from Friend Selector Unity Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

How can I get userID of N selected friends from friend Selector?

Please note, userID not Request ID to excludeIds.

I tried to debug these thing out but coundn't get that. Or is there anyway to get userID of people in friends list who are playing the App.

```
FB.AppRequest(
                message.Value,
                null,
                FriendSelectorFilters,
                excludeIds,
                maxRecipients,
                FriendSelectorData,
                title.Value,
                Callback
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

The user id's are in the FBResult sent to the callback function under the "to" JSON data.

```html
public void FacebookCallback(FBResult r)
{
  Debug.Log(r.text); // Text has the JSON result in it.  You can write a data structure to parse the JSON into for it.
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

{"request":"763399330385682","to":["630312768","7907035","10000083095397","62123666"]}